# Is it possible to hidden .m3u8 link?

Tags: php, stream, m3u8

I would like to create a website that has a stream live video(m3u8 link).
this link only members can find this link.

my code:

```
<video-js id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
      <source src="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8" 
      type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video-js>
```

Is it possible to hide this link???

```
https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8
```

I use the following code that can prevent a user Ctrl + U get the source code
index.html

```
<video-js id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
      <source src="video.php" 
      type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video-js>
```

video.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'] == null){
header("Location: ../login.php");
}
header('Location: https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8');
?>
```

but user still using Chrome dev tool to get link

[image]

Is there best way to hidden the link???

Thank you very much

Comment: The video needs to be displayed on the user's device, so that information needs to get there one way or another. And since the user has full control of the device, they will be able  to do with it whatever they please. What underlying problem are you trying to solve by hiding this URL?